# does Backbone.Models this.get() copy an entire array or point to the same array in memory

Tags: javascript, arrays, backbone.js, model

```
 Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: 'Fetus',
            age: 0,
            children: []
        },
        initialize: function(){
            alert("Welcome to this world");
        },
        adopt: function( newChildsName ){
            var children_array = this.get("children");
            children_array.push( newChildsName );
            this.set({ children: children_array });
        }
    });

    var person = new Person({ name: "Thomas", age: 67, children: ['Ryan']});
    person.adopt('John Resig');
    var children = person.get("children"); // ['Ryan', 'John Resig']
```

In this example code we have:

children_array = this.get("children")

I was thinking this would just point to the same array in memory (and so would be O(1)). However then I thought that would be a design floor because one could manipulate the array without using this.set() and then event listeners wouldn't fire.

So I'm guessing it (somehow magically) copies the array??

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set

What happens?

edit: I just found the implementation in the backbone source code at https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js (I've pasted relevant code at bottom)

Get returns:

```
return this.attributes[attr]
```

so this would just point to the same array in memory right? So one could change the array without using set() and that would be bad.. ? am i correct?

```
get: function(attr) {
      return this.attributes[attr];
    },

    // Get the HTML-escaped value of an attribute.
    escape: function(attr) {
      var html;
      if (html = this._escapedAttributes[attr]) return html;
      var val = this.get(attr);
      return this._escapedAttributes[attr] = _.escape(val == null ? '' : '' + val);
    },

    // Returns `true` if the attribute contains a value that is not null
    // or undefined.
    has: function(attr) {
      return this.get(attr) != null;
    },

    // Set a hash of model attributes on the object, firing `"change"` unless
    // you choose to silence it.
    set: function(key, value, options) {
      var attrs, attr, val;

      // Handle both `"key", value` and `{key: value}` -style arguments.
      if (_.isObject(key) || key == null) {
        attrs = key;
        options = value;
      } else {
        attrs = {};
        attrs[key] = value;
      }

      // Extract attributes and options.
      options || (options = {});
      if (!attrs) return this;
      if (attrs instanceof Model) attrs = attrs.attributes;
      if (options.unset) for (attr in attrs) attrs[attr] = void 0;

      // Run validation.
      if (!this._validate(attrs, options)) return false;

      // Check for changes of `id`.
      if (this.idAttribute in attrs) this.id = attrs[this.idAttribute];

      var changes = options.changes = {};
      var now = this.attributes;
      var escaped = this._escapedAttributes;
      var prev = this._previousAttributes || {};

      // For each `set` attribute...
      for (attr in attrs) {
        val = attrs[attr];

        // If the new and current value differ, record the change.
        if (!_.isEqual(now[attr], val) || (options.unset && _.has(now, attr))) {
          delete escaped[attr];
          (options.silent ? this._silent : changes)[attr] = true;
        }

        // Update or delete the current value.
        options.unset ? delete now[attr] : now[attr] = val;

        // If the new and previous value differ, record the change.  If not,
        // then remove changes for this attribute.
        if (!_.isEqual(prev[attr], val) || (_.has(now, attr) !== _.has(prev, attr))) {
          this.changed[attr] = val;
          if (!options.silent) this._pending[attr] = true;
        } else {
          delete this.changed[attr];
          delete this._pending[attr];
        }
      }

      // Fire the `"change"` events.
      if (!options.silent) this.change(options);
      return this;
    },
```

Comment: "so this would just point to the same array in memory right?" yes and yes.

Comment: @muistooshort right - i was jumping the gun. And so the reason for using .set() is only to fire events? It would be nice if you could summarize in a short answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The documented interface doesn't actually specify who owns the array reference so you're on your own here. If you look at the implementation, you'll see (as you did) that `get` just returns a reference straight out of the model's internal `attributes`. This works fine with immutable types (such as numbers, strings, and booleans) but runs into problems with mutable types such as arrays: you can easily change something without Backbone having any way of knowing about it.

Backbone models appear to be intended to contain primitive types.

There are three reasons to call `set`:

1. That's what the interface specification says to do.
2. If you don't call `set`, you don't trigger events.
3. If you don't call `set`, you'll bypass the validation logic that `set` has.

You just have to be careful if you're working with array and object values.

Note that this behavior of `get` and `set` is an implementation detail and future versions might get smarter about how they handle non-primitive attribute values.

---

The situation with array attributes (and object attributes for that matter) is actually worse than you might initially suspect. When you say `m.set(p, v)`, Backbone won't consider that `set` to be a change if `v === current_value_of_p` so if you pull out an array:

```
var a = m.get(p);
```

then modify it:

```
a.push(x);
```

and send it back in:

```
m.set(p, a);
```

you won't get a `"change"` event from the model because `a === a`; Backbone [actually uses](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L347) Underscore's [`isEqual`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/1.0.0/backbone.js#L347) combined with `!==` but the effect is the same in this case.

For example, this simple bit of chicanery:

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var m = new M({ p: [ 1 ] });
m.on('change', function() { console.log('changed') });

console.log('Set to new array');
m.set('p', [2]);

console.log('Change without set');
m.get('p').push(3);

console.log('Get array, change, and re-set it');
var a = m.get('p'); a.push(4); m.set('p', a);

console.log('Get array, clone it, change it, set it');
a = _(m.get('p')).clone(); a.push(5); m.set('p', a);​
```

produces two `"change"` events: one after the first `set` and one after the last `set`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QwZDv/

If you look at `set` you'll notice that there is some special handling for attributes that are `Backbone.Model`s.

---

The basic lesson here is simple:

> If you're going to use mutable types as attribute values, [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone) them on the way out (or use [`$.extend(true, ...)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) if you need a deep copy) if there is any chance that you'll change the value.

Comment: Thanks - This gives me much more confidence on my initial hunches and then more. strong +1

Comment: This is great, and helped me clarify a lot of confusion on this! It occurs to me that the only missing piece is that a change event will still be fired even if no change occurs (since the set() will still be changing the state of the attribute whether any data has actually changed or not). For a solution I suggest comparing the two arrays, the new one and the current one in the attribute, before deciding whether to call set(). This can be done using underscore's _.difference(). Info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755313/compare-two-arrays-if-keys-match-with-underscore-js

Comment: Thanks @mu-is-too-short, nice answer! Your demo is not working anymore, so I made a fork if someone wants to check the described behaviour: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/petjofi/m07thgr9/1/)

Comment: @PetarKrivoshiev Thanks for letting me know, I just updated the fiddle to use the latest jQuery and pull the latest Underscore and Backbone off a CDN (rather than the old Github versions).