# compare two arrays if keys match with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array with permissions from Facebook and an array of the permissions that the user shouldve given:

```
window.FB.api('/me/permissions', function(perm){                     
    if(perm){
       var given_permissions =  _.keys(perm['data'][0];
       var needed_permissions = ["publish_stream", "email"];
       //now check if given permissions contains needed permissions
    }
}
```

Now I want to compare if all the `needed_permissions` are in `given_permissions`, in an underscore savvy way (without looping two arrays myself and compare values). I saw a `_.include` method, but this compares an array with a value. I want to return true if all the permissions are available and else a false. I was looking for a nice single line call if possible.

The reason for this is, that `FB.login` returns true even if the user chooses to cancel the extended permissions. So I need to doublecheck this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
_.all(needed_permissions, function(v){
    return _.include(given_permissions, v);
});
```

Answer (score 18):

You could use [`_.difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) to see if removing the given permissions from your required permissions leaves anything behind:

```
var diff = _(needed_permissions).difference(given_permissions)
if(diff.length > 0)
    // Some permissions were not granted
```

A nice side effect of this is that you get the missing permissions in `diff` in case you want to tell them what's wrong.

Comment: That's also a nice solution. I'll have to mark the other one as answer, because that's basicly what I asked for, but I think I'll use this solution so I can provide better feedback.

Comment: I disagree and think it would be much more useful to make this your accepted answer. _.difference is exactly what you asked for ("compare two arrays if keys match with underscore.js" - the rest was really speculation I think) and indeed the answer you "accepted" because you used it! Just a thought to help others looking at this. I guess not everyone will check past the accepted answer. The accepted answer is pretty poor as a solution since it adds nothing when underscore provides a function to do exactly that "out of the box".

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but this works for me: `_.isEqual(given_permissions, needed_permissions);`