# Store/push to an array in a Backbone Model

Tags: backbone.js

I have this model defaults:

```
test.Models.ItemModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {
    name: 'an item',
    units: []
},
```

Which I then use the following code to set the Model:

```
 addUnit: function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
      this.model.set({ 'units' : this.model.get('units').push($('#addUnit').val()) }, 
        {success: function(){
          this.render();
        }}
      );
    }
  },
```

However, it never seems to get added to the Model array, am I doing things right here??

Comment: Be careful with that array in `defaults`, `defaults` is shallow-copied so you can end up with several models referencing the exact same array that is (still) in `defaults`. A function (`defaults: function() { return { ... } }`) is safer when you have arrays or objects in `defaults`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're assuming the the `push` method is returning the whole array; instead, [as stated here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), the `push` method

> Returns the new `length` property of the object upon which the method was called.

So, you need to push the element into the array before you set it to the model :

```
var _units = this.model.get('units');
_units.push($('#addUnit').val());
this.model.set({ 'units' : _units });
```

Careful though, this will modify anything else that points to this array, so if you do this, for example:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3]
this.model.set({units: myArray})
var _units = this.model.get('units')
_units.push(4)
this.model.set({ 'units' : _units })
myArray == this.model.get('units') // holy moly, they're the same :(
```

If you want to avoid this, or still want to use a single line of code for that, you could use array's [`concat` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
this.model.set({ 
    'units' : this.model.get('units').concat($('#addUnit').val())
});
```

Comment: Your first one won't trigger a `"change"` event when you call `set` since the underlying attribute value hasn't changed (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11662381/479863), you have to use some variant of the second (`concat`, `_.clone` and `push`, or something else that doesn't touch the original array) to get good results.

Comment: Definitely a good note, @muistooshort. Wanna use the concat method instead. If you don't, it will modify the passed in array.

Comment: yes, change event it is not triggered with this solution, needs to be updated