# BackboneJS How to remove item of Model array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to delete/remove a specific item inside my Backbone Model Array. My Model returns this data (json)

```
"data":  {
   "id": 16268,
   "releases":  [
      {"title" :"title1", "cover" : "some image", "releasedate": "some date"},
      {"title" :"title2", "cover" : "some image", "releasedate": "some date"},
      {"title" :"title3", "cover" : "some image", "releasedate": "some date"},
      {"title" :"title4", "cover" : "some image", "releasedate": "some date"},
      {"title" :"title5", "cover" : "some image", "releasedate": "some date"},
  ]
}
```

So, lets say I want to delete/remove the second entry. I tried to do this:

```
if(this.model.get('id') === 16268){
        if(this.model.get('releases')[1]) {
           this.model.remove();
        }
}
```

but with no luck. Can someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: what exactly u need to remove, + if i'm not mistaken model dont have `remove` method, collection has

Comment: yeah, unfortunately... I need to remove second item, but still don't know how to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove element with certain index from array you have to use Array's [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

In order to get `"change"` event fired on your model you can use Model's `set` method in conjunction with Array's [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method which returns a copy of array.

So the code removing array element should look like this:

```
var arr = this.model.get('releases');
arr.splice(1, 1);
this.model.set('releases', arr.slice());
```

Comment: @Steve This seems to be a correct way of doing things. Are there any errors you can note?

Comment: @Steve You have to clarify what exactly doesn't work. Also you have to post your full code as the problem may be hidden in other place

Comment: This won't work because you haven't [changed the array](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11662381/479863), you've only changed its contents.

Comment: @mu is too short That's right. Thanks for the note. I've updated the answer with the fix

Comment: @Steve You could upvote my answer as well if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Create a "release" model, then add an attribute to your current model that'd be a release collection(backbone collection). After that you can manipulate the collection as you need.

Thanks.